# Syntax error GROUP BY assign HAVING COUNT (*) > 1 LIMIT 0, 25

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find duplicates on assign column but for some unkown reason I get an error from phpMyAdmin.

```
select asin COUNT(*) FROM `amazon-crawler` GROUP BY asin HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: asin count(*) is not valid syntax: You are aliasing a field asin as count(*)

Comment: What is `asin count(*)`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma (`,`) between the two expressions in your select list:

```
SELECT asin, COUNT(*) FROM `amazon-crawler` GROUP BY asin HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
-- Here ---^
```